# = stylesheet_link_tag devise Completed 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, npm

I have a very weird situation, I setup Devise and now I'm getting:

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized
```

and the home#page never ends loading. I noted that if I remove:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'mainstyles'
```

from my application layout, I can load the page but I don't know how a stylesheet_link_tag is related with a 401 code.

**SOLVED**:

My error was put all the npm modules in APP/assets/ instead of APP/lib/assets/

I guess rails was trying to compile all the 500 MB of JS modules and of course that the reason about the endless loading.

Comment: If you solve your own question you may also add an answer yourself.